# Does an extjs combo box need to be inside a Form in order to submit arbitrary text?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I'm using extjs 3.4.0.

I'm trying to figure out how combo box is different if I only need it to be able to select items from a list or if I also would like it to have the ability to submit arbitrary text.

Looks like forceSelection: true/false is the key config option here, with forceSelection: true one can only select an item from the drop down menu, with forceSelection: false one should be able to type arbitrary text.

Querying the server and getting the drop down menu with the matching options works well, but I can't get it to submit my arbitrary text (something not on the drop down menu). If I just type the queries are submitted, but if there aren't any matches then by pressing Enter nothing happens even though I'd expect Enter would send the request, similarly how a request is sent when searching for matches.

Do I need to put the combo box inside a Form instance in order to submit the arbitrary text? That would feel strange since the combo box is perfectly capable of sending a request when it does the search for matches.

***Update***:

This is the actual code I have:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: '/store',
    root: 'items',
    totalProperty: 'count', 
    fields: Ext.data.Record.create( [ 'name', 'id' ] ),
    id: 'id' });

var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    store: store,
    forceSelection: false,
    typeAhead: true,
    loadingText: '',
    width: 170,
    hideTrigger: true,
    itemSelector: 'div.item',
    applyTo: 'div.box',
    queryParam: 'tx', 
    hiddenValue: 'something',
    name: 'name',
    displayField: 'name',
    submitValue: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    onSelect: function( record ) { alert( record.data.name ); }
    });
```

Comment: Daniel, can you paste in the code for your combo box?

Comment: Sure, I've added the code, so querying for matching results works perfectly well with the above, but if arbitrary text is typed and then Enter is pressed nothing happens.

Comment: I dropped that code (most of it anyway) into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sherburne/VYwSC/) and the combo box works like you're asking for (I think). There could be something happening with the rest of the form. One thought I had was that arbitrary text isn't going to map to an 'id' so the combo wouldn't know what to return if the raw value was arbitrary text, but that's not the case with the fiddled combo - arbitrary text is returned from the call to getValue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it seems the combo does work, but one has to explicitly submit the arbitrary text entry by pressing a button. By simply pressing Enter in the combo box text field the query is not sent. But that's okay actually, I'll just add a button.